# Period in CSS, does it do anything?

Tags: css

I'm dealing with someone else's code here and have come across something like this:

```
.selector {
 .background-position : 0px 2px;
}
```

Does the period **on the line background-position** do anything or was that their way of commenting the line out? It doesn't seem to have an effect that I know of (using chrome inspector and firefox inspector) but I want to make sure.

Thanks for any insight on this.

Comment: That looks like a broken way to comment the line out.

Comment: Strange; I've never seen that before. I don't see any mention of it in W3C standards...

Comment: When the only way to properly comment stuff out is `/* ... */`, it's a very convenient way to quickly disable something to see how it looks in the browser, then decide whether to keep it or remove it.

Comment: Could that be a css hack, there have been a lot of cs hacks, where extra symbols were added to attributes, to fix certain browser behaviours.

Comment: Doesn't look like a hack. Hacks usually employ parsing bugs. It's extremely unlikely for even the worst programmer at Microsoft to have a bug in parsing that line...

Comment: I'm not aware of any hacks that start with a period.

Comment: I think it is a typo that wasn't noticed.

Comment: I don't think it was a typo because they're all over the place. I'm pretty sure it was his way of commenting things out...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use a z to quickly comment stuff out. But in the production CSS, I remove these lines.

It's a "comment". It makes the CSS invalid though and it looks very unprofessional, so it's a good idea to remove it altogether if you don't need it, or at least properly comment it with `/* ... */`.

Comment: That's what I did, just wanted to check before I moved it to production.

Answer (score 4):

A period there - ie in `.background-position` - is not valid CSS.

A period *is* valid in the selector, as you've shown it - ie `.selector`, in which case it selects elements with `class='selector'`.

But if I understand the question, you were asking about the dot in `.background-position`, which as I say is not valid. If you try to add `.background-position` as a style in Firebug, it won't accept it.

Answer (score 2):

That isn't valid CSS; my guess is it's a comment or a mistake.

I have seen people use characters like _ and * to make sure some properties are only rendered in particular browsers (for example _background-position would be applied in only IE6), but never seen it done with a '.'

Answer (score 0):

Period prefixes indicate styles exclusive to IE7
[CSS Browser Hacks](http://www.coding4streetcred.com/blog/post/CSS-Cross-Browser-Hacks.aspx)

Comment: Thanks... would have been nice if the previous developer had commented that or put it in the stylesheet meant for that. I already took them out in some places and that was in May so I probably would have heard about it by now... but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I have not been able to find another source to confirm this... do you know of one?

Comment: It was recently added to a minify tool that miscrosoft maintains, which is how I found out about it. It is referenced in the release notes. Other then that and seeing it used in my organization it appears to be rather uncommon. http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/releases/view/76233