# Does the minus sign or underscore in css do anything?

Tags: css

This question is similar to the one I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110816/period-in-css-does-it-do-anything).  I am cleaning up some files and I came across this in this css:

```
.something
{
  height: 33px;
  -height: 34px; /* does this do anything?? /
}
```

and

```
.something
{
  _width: 150px; / does this do anything?? */
}
```

EDIT: Okay, so the _ (underscore) is a css hack for IE, which is fine, I'll just leave it, but what about the minus sign, does it do anything at all?

Also, we are not supporting anything below IE 7 anymore, so if anything is a hack for IE6 I can take it out.

Comment: _width: 150px; This is IE6-7 css hack as I remember.

Comment: Using `-property: value` is a bad choice. The recognized variant is `_property: value`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Straight from the [**W3C CSS 2.1 Spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#vendor-keywords) -

> **4.1.2.1 Vendor-specific extensions**
>
> In CSS, identifiers may begin with '`-`' (dash) or '`_`' (underscore). Keywords
>   and property names beginning with '`-`' or '`_`' are reserved for vendor-specific extensions.

However that said, using an underscore to prefix a CSS property is a [well known CSS hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Underscore_hack) to apply that rule for rendering in IE 6.

Since a CSS identifier can start with a '`-`' (dash) and be valid, this can be used to quickly comment out parts of CSS during development. For example in the CSS below, none of the properties will be set for `h1` and only `margin` will be set for `h2`.

```
-h1 { color:blue; margin:2em; }
h2 { -color:pink; margin:2em; } /* property "-color" not valid */
```

Answer (score 2):

It means the CSS property will be applied in IE 6 and below. It is a [*CSS hack*](http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks#unrecommended-vendor_prefix).

A cleaner method of applying styles to different IEs is using [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Comment: Obligatory reading for the CSS-hacks-vs-conditional-comments battle: http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the minus sign, but the underscore is a hack to have a rule ignored in IE < 6.

http://wellstyled.com/css-underscore-hack.html

Answer (score 2):

This is a [CSS hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Underscore_hack), to trick some browsers to use them (or not use them). 
This one is the [Underscore Hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Underscore_hack)

> Versions 6 and below of Internet
>   Explorer recognize properties with
>   this prefix (after discarding the
>   prefix). All other browsers ignore
>   such properties as invalid. Therefore,
>   a property that is preceded by an
>   underscore or a hyphen is applied
>   exclusively in Internet Explorer 6 and
>   below.
>
> ```
> #elem {   
>          width: [W3C Model Width];   
>          _width: [BorderBox Model]; 
>       }
> ```
>
> This hack uses invalid CSS[3] and
>   there are valid CSS directives to
>   accomplish a similar result. Thus some
>   people do not recommend using it. On
>   the other hand this hack does not
>   change the specificity of a selector
>   making maintenance and extension of a
>   CSS file easier.

CSS Hacks is one (not so elegant) technique of achieving same look and feel and across browsers.